# MySQL assuming I want none of the results based on operators used

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a messaging table with columns that I run some operators on.  There are several threadid's and I pull the messages by checking if a value matches uidto or uidfrom, then checking if a value is in hidden1 or hidden2 (or basically one user deleted the thread, but we want to keep it visible to the other user still...)

edit:
Of note, the value of the hidden1 and hidden2 columns is the users id who has opted to hide the thread from himself.

When there are multiple threads for a users, and I set one thread as deleted (hidden1 value = 1) then the query won't pull any of the other threads, despite their hidden1 and hidden2 columns remaining NULL.

I have an SQL Fiddle here with data in the table and the queries I've been playing with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3c39c/3

show all results with multiple threadid
note only threadid 1 has column hidden1 with a value

```
SELECT uidto, uidfrom, threadid, hidden1, hidden2 FROM messages;
```

attempt to pull results
mysql sees one of my threads with column hidden1 with value and shows none, even though the other threads hidden1 and hidden2 columns are still NULL?

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE (uidto=1 OR uidfrom=1)
AND (hidden1 <> 1 OR hidden2 <> 1)
GROUP BY threadid
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

Comment: I think a more normalized database design will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

[Any sort of arithmetic comparison against NULL always returns NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) and is treated as false; in this case, that means `hidden1 <> 1`, where hidden1 is NULL, returns an effectively false value, despite the fact that NULL is manifestly not equal to 1, or indeed to anything else including itself. (Try it! `SELECT NULL = NULL` and you get back NULL.)

To solve the problem, replace the inequality comparison with `IS NULL`, or (preferably) use integer zero rather than NULL to represent your false value, so that you can use arithmetic comparisons for truth testing.

Without changing your data, you can get the query working by replacing the comparison with one which is NULL-aware, thus:

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE (uidto=1 OR uidfrom=1)
    AND (hidden1 IS NULL OR hidden2 IS NULL)
GROUP BY threadid
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

whose result is

```
ID  UIDTO   UIDFROM     THREADID    MESSAGE     STATUS  DATETIME                            LAST_ACTIVITY                       LAST_MESSAGE            HIDDEN2     HIDDEN1     TYPE
1   10002   1           1           hey         0       November, 14 2013   00:28:58+0000   November, 14 2013 00:36:13+0000     hans here.              (null)      1           message
3   15047   1           3           CJ TO BG    0       November, 14 2013   00:34:53+0000   November, 14 2013 00:34:53+0000     CJ TO BG                (null)      (null)      message
```

(See also [the updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3c39c/6).)

Comment: I should have noted that I am not just using hidden1 = 1 to signify that it is not only not NULL but also that is the users id who has marked it as hidden. For example if user id 10 marks that thread as hidden then hidden1 value becomes 10. 

Likewise if user 20 was a party to the same thread and he also marked it deleted, his user id would become the value of column hidden2.

Does that make sense? I've updated the questions to note that.

Comment: @cjaredrun That does make sense; however, unless 0 is a valid user ID, you might still want to consider using it instead of NULL, just to avoid the headaches inherent in dealing with the latter. On the other hand, you'll need to get used to dealing with it *some* time...